# Counting Operations to Produce Polynomials

Tags: big-o, counting, polynomials, operations

#### I am struggling to accurately count the operations for this method in order to produce a polynomial f(x):

```
public static int numOccurrences(int n){   
    int count = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){   
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){    
           if(i == j) {
              continue; 
           }       
           if(strings[i] == strings[j]){
              count++;    
           }   
        } 
     }  
    return count; 
}
```

#### So far this is my understanding:

```
    int count = 0;  //1 time
    int i = 0;      //1 time
    while(i < n)    //n times
    int j = 0;      //n times
    while(j<n)      //n*n times 
    if(i == j)      //n*n times
    continue;       //n times
    if(strings[i] == strings[j]) //n*n+2 times
    count++;        //n*n times  
    i++             //n*n times
    j++             //n*n times
    return count;   //1 time
```

One we are inside of a nested loop with the if statements, I am wondering how I count the operations if what I have above is incorrect?

Also, for the line `if(strings[i] == strings[j])` I am counting 1 for the test, 1 for grabbing `strings[i]` and 1 for `strings[j]`. Is this correct?

My final answer was: **f(x) = 5n^4+10n^3+3n+3**

*and I sincerely apologize if this is insanely incorrect!*

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share my answer just in case someone stumbles upon this post.
An **easier** way of producing a polynomial that I discovered from a tutor today is to count each operation, BUT instead of writing out that everything inside a loop happens n*n times, we would simply count the single steps and nest the those individual steps (like i++) inside of n.

For example:

```
int count = 0;  //1 
int i = 0;      //+ 1 
while(i < n)    //+ n(
i++;            //+ 1
int j = 0;      //+ 1
while(j < n)    //+ n(
j++             //+ 1
if(i == j)      //+ 1
continue;       //+ 1
if(strings[i] == strings[j]) //+ 3
count++;        //+ 1
return count;   //+ 1
```

add all of them up, we get = 1+1+n(1+1+n(1+1+1+3+1))+1

**Simplify = 6n^2+2n+3**